# GAE change field name/attribute

Tags: google-app-engine, model, google-cloud-datastore

Is it possiible to change attribute name on db.Model kind? i have some field name created with dash (e.g. field-name) that resulting error.

```
class DataBulk(db.Model):
    group_id = db.IntegerProperty()
    group_name = db.StringProperty()
    geo_pos = db.GeoPtProperty()
    group-leader = db.StringProperty() <-----------error 
    imported = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
```

Anyone can tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use valid Python names to define properties like that. Strictly speaking you **can** define the name that is stored in datastore, passing an argument "name" to the property:

```
class DataBulk(db.Model):
    group_id = db.IntegerProperty()
    group_leader = db.StringProperty(name='group-leader')
```